# I installed the Tensorflow gpu version and CUDA 9.1 and python 3.6.5. However, after I import the tensorflow-gpu I got the following error:

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "C:\Users\ranji\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\self_check.py", line 75, in preload_check
    ctypes.WinDLL(build_info.cudart_dll_name)
  File "C:\Users\ranji\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 348, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ranji/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/ts1.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\ranji\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Users\ranji\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\ranji\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 30, in <module>
    self_check.preload_check()
  File "C:\Users\ranji\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\self_check.py", line 82, in preload_check
    % (build_info.cudart_dll_name, build_info.cuda_version_number))
ImportError: Could not find 'cudart64_90.dll'. TensorFlow requires that this DLL be installed in a directory that is named in your %PATH% environment variable. Download and install CUDA 9.0 from this URL: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit
```

Answer (score 2):

> Currently Tensorflow is only supporting CUDA **9.0**

But you have installed CUDA 9.1. You now have two options:

- Option 1:  You compile Tensorflow from source, this then enables support for your CUDA version 9.1
- Option 2: You **install CUDA 9.0** and wait until Tensorflow supports CUDA 9.1

I went through the same pain and have decided to install CUDA 9.0. It is probably less of a hassle.

Also refer to this [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/15656) regarding the current status of Tensorflow support for CUDA 9.1 and how to compile Tensorflow from source.